# Emulator doesn't work with AMD Ryzen and Windows home

Tags: android-emulator

I own a laptop which has amd ryzen 5 CPU in it. Unfortunately the emulator doesn't work. And I couldn't enable Hyper-V because my Windows is Windows 10 Home. Now I am using arm emulator, but it is too slow to work with. Is there any other option to solve this problem?

Comment: Friendly reminder the emulator isn't called the "Android Studio" emulator - it's a part of the SDK and has nothing to do with the IDE. If I decided to make an app with Vim and installed the SDK, the emulator would be the *exact* same one

Answer (score 0):

The best option, imo, is to use visual studio emulator. In order to work you need to add a line to Windows registry (that was my case, at least), and then it will run in lollipop or marshmallow, at best, I think. Anyway, it's pretty fast.

Other than that, read this as it may be useful: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html?m=1

An alternative option would be to switch to Linux distribution, like Ubuntu.